# How to load exe with reflection if exe does not have a manifest?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a dump of an executable file (Runtime: v2.0.50727). It works well without any mistakes. I could load it to DnSpy to debug or to ILSpy. Both of them tells that all references successfully resolved.

However, I can't load it using this code:

```
try
{
    var second_module = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("myprog.bin");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///myprog.bin' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
File name: 'file:///myprog.bin'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at myproggg.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Sources\My\myproggg\Program.cs:line 11

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = myprog.bin
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/Sources/My/myproggg/bin/x86/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\Sources\My\myproggg\bin\x86\Debug\myproggg.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/Sources/My/MPCExtractor/examples/MP/myprog.bin.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

I tried to do these steps:

1. Changing compile option from "Any CPU" to "x86". No difference.
2. Changing framework to 2.0 and to 4.5. No matter what framework I use, it anyway asks me about manifest.

Nothing of the above helped me.

What can I do more to load this dumped executable?

Comment: Have a try with the `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(byte[] rawAssembly);` overload.

Comment: Thank you for your magic! But why does this method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bin` file you created tracks back to COFF, which .NET 2.0 runtime uses. You can also use  [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160), to get a `.bin` file. The documentation states

> The Microsoft COFF Binary File Dumper (DUMPBIN.EXE) displays information about Common Object File Format (COFF) binary files.

So, to properly load that, you will need to use [Assembly.Load(byte[], ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Byte___System_Byte___). That documentation states that its parameter accepts a raw [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) array of bytes:

> A byte array that is a COFF-based image containing an emitted assembly.

This part from the above source may also be relevant to you

> Reflecting on C++ executable files might throw a [BadImageFormatException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-5.0). This is most likely caused by the C++ compiler stripping the relocation addresses or the `.reloc` section from your executable file. To preserve the `.reloc` address for your C++ executable file, specify `/fixed:no` when you are linking.

Comment: Actually I didn't use dumpbin. I've made a dump of process in suspended state before execution starts, rebuild it to fix virtual sizes and... forgot to restore relocs. Finally, you hit the nail. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. That still tracks back to COFF based on that runtime version. Glad you're unstuck!